# Data incorrect entry in php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form in html with various fields, in particular a select and textarea. by pressing the button I create other n select and textarea (n given by keyboard).
I then have a php file that inserts the data into the database. everything works but not correctly inserted the data of the textarea (which in the file called $quantita) that does not take all the order (for sesmpio if I write 1, 2, 5 inserts 1,2,5) but only a value (if I write just takes 1,2,5 1,1,1).
html

```
<?php
    $pro = 'sito';
    $dd = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', $pro);
    $re = mysqli_query ($dd,"SELECT Codice, Nome FROM prodotti");
    echo"<div class='box'>";
    echo"Prodotto";
    echo"<select class='inse' name='po[]'>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($re)){
            echo"<option value=".$row['Codice'].">".$row['Nome']."</option>";
    }
    echo"</select>";
    echo"<br>";
    echo"Quantit&agrave; <textarea name='qua[]' rows='1' cols='4'></textarea></div><br>";
    ?> 
             </div>
    <br><button type="submit" id="ok">OK!</button><br>
</form>
```

php

```
<?php
    $nordine = $_POST['nor'];
    $datao = $_POST['dao'];
    $datac = $_POST['dac'];
    $quantita = $_POST['qua'];
    $prodotto = $_POST['po'];

    $data = 'sito';
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', $data);
    $result = mysqli_multi_query ($db, "INSERT INTO ordini 
                                        (Nordine,DataO,DataC) 
                                        VALUES('$nordine','$datao','$datac')");
    if ($prodotto && $quantita){
        foreach ($prodotto as $result1){
            foreach ($quantita as $result2){
                mysqli_query ($db, "INSERT INTO ordpro 
                                    (Prodotto, Ordini, Quantita) 
                                VALUES('". mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$result1)."','$nordine','". mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$result2)."')");
            }
        }
    }   

    echo"<p>Hai inserito un nuovo record <a href='ordini.php'> torna alla home </a></p>";
?>
```

Comment: SQL-Injection fest spotted!

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: The beauty of mysqli is that it affords the use of prepared statements, so take a look at how to incorporate those into your code (or switch to PDO). That said, it can be easier to debug queries when written out as above, so I'd advocate getting the code working first and then incorporating prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your HTML I think that `po[0]` should go with `qua[0]` and `po[1]` should go with `qua[1]` etc etc

So your 2 foreach loops are doing the wrong thing and storing all the `qua`s with each `po`

You should also be using prepared and paramterised statement when using any data provided by the user in POST or GET.

An additional benefit of using prepared statements for multiple updates is that you can prepare it once and execute it many times, thus reducing the round trips to the database. Also the query needs to be compiled and optimized by MYSQL only once, making it almost like using a Stored Procedure.

> NOTE: This also means you no longer need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on the users data.

So the loops should be amended like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ordpro (Prodotto, Ordini, Quantita) VALUES (?,?,?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $sql);

if ($prodotto && $quantita){
    foreach ($prodotto as $idx => $prod){
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $prod, $nordine, $quantita[$idx]);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

> Note2 I have used `sss` (string) as the data types for all 3 variables. You may need to check that this is correct and amend accordingly. The id fields may need to be changed to `i` where appropriate